# findContours crashes the code

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Im trying to simply find contours and draw.but the code crashes when it reaches `findContours()` .I passed it a frame from `inRange`    `Canny` `convertTo` but no hope yet.

any suggestions?

this is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Mat HSVFrame, cfilterFrame, edgeFrame, Frame ;
    vector<vector<Point>> cnts;
    vector<Vec4i> hichy;
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    namedWindow("w", 1);


    while(true){
     cap >> Frame;

    if(Frame.empty()){
        break;
    }
     cv::cvtColor(Frame,HSVFrame,CV_BGR2HSV);



     cv::inRange(HSVFrame , Scalar(0,155,60), Scalar(10,255,255), cfilterFrame);




     cv::Canny(cfilterFrame , edgeFrame, 50,150 , 3);




  // cfilterFrame.convertTo(edgeFrame, CV_8U ); //also tried this


    cv::findContours(edgeFrame, cnts, hichy, CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

 for(int i =0 ; i < cnts.size() ; i++){
        drawContours(Frame,cnts,i,Scalar(0,0,255),2, 8, hichy,0,Point(0,0));
    }


imshow("w", Frame);
waitKey(30);
    }
    return a.exec();

}
```

.pro:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = sevventhTry
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp


INCLUDEPATH += C://opencv//build//include
CONFIG(debug,debug|release){
LIBS += -LC://opencv//build//x86//vc12//lib\
-lopencv_world300\
-lopencv_world300d\
-lopencv_ts300d \
-lopencv_ts300
}
```

Qt creator 3.5.1 Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2013 
openCV 3.0 
win 8 x64

Comment: This is usually caused by linking wrong libraries. Do you have Qt compiled with vc12 64bit? Are you using OpenCV compiled with vc12 64 bit? Are you mixing release and debug libs?

Comment: @Miki  its qt vs12 32bit with opencv vs12 32bit. I can use houghcircles and houghlines .Canny and inRange are working fine

Comment: Ok, all 32 bit. Please check if you're mixing release and debug libs. Other functions may work, but `findContours` crashes.

Comment: @Miki  a contrib.hpp missing in includes for release

Comment: check libraries, not headers

Comment: @Miki `-lopencv_world300\
-lopencv_world300d\
-lopencv_ts300d \
-lopencv_ts300` this is all existing libs in opencv folder

Comment: don't link both debug and release together. Link debug libs in debug, and relase libs in release

Comment: @Miki you mean dont use this ? `CONFIG(debug,debug|release)` ? how can I link release libs in release? thank you for your help

Comment: Yeah, I mean **use it** to link to debug libs in debug mode, and release libs for release. Can you post you pro file?

Comment: remove the libs without the trailing **d**, since you're linking for debug

Comment: @Miki I CANT BELIEVE THAT WORKED. thank you so much.but what about release? on release it gives me tons of errors

Comment: `CONFIG(debug,debug|release){` means that youre linking for debug mode. Make a `CONFIG(release,debug|release){` for the release libs